# Bash script spawns many new processes of itself

Tags: bash

The script that I am working on right now is used to save data from 3 columns into three different arrays, which will be used for a different part later.

Right now the script callconv.sh looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash 
array=$(sqlite3 /home/pi/dir/rec_call/CallRecords.sqlitedb "SELECT address FROM calls")
array2=$(sqlite3 /home/pi/dir/rec_call/CallRecords.sqlitedb "SELECT timestamp FROM calls")
array3=$(sqlite3 /home/pi/dir/rec_call/CallRecords.sqlitedb "SELECT date FROM calls")

Rest of script...
```

The problem is that as soon as I run callconv.sh, only containing these 3 lines about 30 or 40 new processes named callconv.sh and sqlite3 are created. Many of them with the defunct tag to be specific.

I want the script to run on my Raspberry Pi with Raspbmc, but that does not work. However, when I try running it on my CentOS vps it runs without any problems. Is it possible that the issue is related to the OS or could you guys tell me if I have done something obviously wrong here? 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. I meant that these three lines are causing the issue. When I remove the rest of the script the issue is still there, it is those 3 lines that are the cause.

Comment: Show us the complete script and the `ps` output. Seeing subprocesses is normal: you're creating them, but from that part of the script there would be only a single one at a time.

Comment: @nStgmk You should edit your question for such additional information instead of writing comments. That is true for information which is requested by others via comments, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you listing processes to find "30 or 40" of them? Are you sure you are not looking at *threads* rather than *processes*? It is common for advanced programs (such as databases) to spawn multiple threads when starting up.

Side note: That code will not create [arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) - the standard output of the `sqlite3` commands will be saved as **string** variables. If you want to save command output (separated by `$IFS`) as arrays you need to use `my_variable=($(my_command))`.

Comment: Your side note did it for me. The problem was that I did not have arrays, but strings. The link was very informative and I definitely need to read up on this. Thank you very much for your help!